# Token request to keycloak behind docker, curl works, reactjs does not

Tags: curl, docker, cors, keycloak, docker-for-windows

Following situation:

Keycloak server is setup with docker compose (http://127.0.0.1:8083)

When I do this:

```
curl --data "grant_type=password&client_id=account&username=dr&password=dr" http://127.0.0.1:8083/auth/realms/xxx/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

it works.

Then I try to do the same on react.js with following:

```
axios.post(kc.authServerUrl + "/realms/xxx/protocol/openid-connect/token", {
    grant_type: 'password',
    client_id: 'account',
    username: 'dr',
    password: 'dr'
}
)
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

And it does not work. I get the following:

[image]

Sidenotes:
On keycloak I have set allow origin from *
Also strange: I see user has opened sessions from ip 172.17.0.1 (that is I guess caused by curl)

Question: How to make it work from react.js? 
Question 2: Why is it working from curl and not with axios?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this seems to work:

```
fetch(kc.authServerUrl + "/realms/xxx/protocol/openid-connect/token", {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: 'grant_type=password&client_id=account&username=dr&password=dr'
    });
```

Comment: Can't tell you the problems I had with axios. Not surprised fetch worked.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution if some people, like me, wants to insist on using axios.

As it is said in axios wiki, by default, axios serializes JavaScript objects to JSON. So to send data in the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` you can do this :

```
var params = new URLSearchParams();

params.append('grant_type', 'password');
params.append('client_id', 'account');
params.append('username', 'dr');
params.append('password', 'dr');

axios.post('/realms/xxx/protocol/openid-connect/token', params);
```

or you can do this with the qs library :

```
import qs from 'querystring';

let data = {
  grant_type: 'password',
  client_id: 'account',
  username: 'dr',
  password: 'dr'
};

axios.post('/reals/xxx/protocol/openid-connect/token', qs.stringify(data));
```